# Polymer CLI --env type global option from application

Tags: development-environment, polymer-2.x, polymer-cli

There is a **--env type** global option available for polymer cli. I'm looking for way to use dev environment specific code that doesn't compile into production application. Is there a way to access *--env type* from application?

or any other workaround ?